# access/copy/delete the files of root folder from the azure app service(web app) using another web application

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, wwwroot

We want to copy or delete the files from the root folder of `Azure app service(web app)`.

We have multiple web application hosted in azure, we need to copy/download and delete the files from the root folder of all the web application using another web application.

Note: we are creating new web app which will access the other web application's root folder and copy/delete the files.

```cs
d:\\home\site\wwwroot\LogFiles
```

Answer (score 1):

> delete the files from the root folder of `Azure app service(web app)`

***For the Azure Windows App Service:***

- If the Web App is deployed to `Azure Windows App Service`, you will find an option to delete the files in KUDU Console.
  ***Path to KUDU*** - `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

***OR***

Navigate to your deployed App => `Advanced Tools` => `Go`

[image]

`Debug console` => `cmd` => `site` => `wwwroot` , you will find all the deployed files/folders.
Option to `edit/delete/download` can be seen.

[image]

***For the Azure Linux App Service:***

Thanks @[Dillion Megida](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-linux/) for the commands.

In the Azure Linux App Service, navigate to `DebugConsole` =>`Bash`  => `site` => `wwwroot` folder.

with `ls`, you can see the existing files and folders.

- Navigate to the folder where you want to delete the files.

run the below command to delete a single file.

`rm filename`

***Ex:*** `rm appsettings.json`

[image]

To delete folder/directory, use the below command.

`rm -r FolderName`

[image]

### Update:

Thanks [@Niels Swimberghe](https://swimburger.net/blog/azure/deleting-old-web-app-logs-using-azure-web-jobs-and-powershell) for the `PowerShell` Script.

Create a PowerShell script with the `LogFiles` path and save as `.ps1` extension.

> ```cs
> $LogFolder = "C:\home\LogFiles";
> $DaysToKeepLogsAround = 30;
> Get-ChildItem -Path $LogFolder -Recurse ->File | Where LastWriteTime  -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysToKeepLogsAround) | Remove-Item -Force
> ```

- In the Deployed `App service` => `Web Jobs` => `Create a Web Job` .

[image]

- Select the `WebJob` and click on run to test the script.
- You can see the files before 30 days got deleted.

[image]

- Check the `WebJob Status` under Logs.

[image]

Comment: He does not want to delete files manually or by going to the KUDO, etc. What he wants is for another app (probably a function app or web API) to connect to these paths (as he has multiple sites hosted) and access the files and delete them from a single place via code.

Comment: Ok..Will work on it and let you know.

Comment: @Meghraj Belikatti - Do you want to delete all the `LogFiles`?

Comment: No @Harshitha, we want to delete the files which are created one month before.

Comment: File means , are you looking for any particular folder ? or the files under `LogFiles` ?

Comment: Yes, we want to delete/copy/download the files under the LogFiles folder.

Comment: @Meghraj Belikatti - Please check the `Update` section in the posted answer.

Comment: @Harshitha - As I mentioned, we want to do this functionality through Web App or Function App. We have already one pipeline in place, but we want to do this through the Web App or Function app.

Comment: I haven't found any code related to deleting the Azure logs from c# code. AFAIK, `Powershell` Script with `Azure Web Jobs` is the easy option to delete the Azure log files.